# How I can compare two iOS local web-servers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, gcdwebserver, cocoahttpserver

I created an iOS app prototype that runs two web servers ([CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) and [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)). And I want to choose the best one.
I need to use a local web-server as a backend for JS-application (Will God Forgive Me?) that will shown in `WKWebView` in this application.

So, can you please suggest me, how I can compare the perfomance of these two servers? 
Which kind of tests should I perform and how? 
What are the indicators I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend GCDWebServer, as it is actively supported (though mature and stable).  To the best of my knowledge CocoaHTTPServer is not currently being actively maintained.